# When is the right eigenvector of a Markov Chain not constant?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, python, programming

As far as I know, it is well known that the top right eigenvector of a row-stochastic matrix is the all-ones vector, and that the top left eigenvector of this same matrix is the stationary distribution. However, I don't get this result when I use the `numpy.linalg.svd` function from `Python` (in fact, no software I tried gives me this). I would like to know why. **Am I wrong in expecting to get the all-ones vector as the right eigenvector of a row-stochastic matrix?**

To be specific, consider [this Markov Chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQCdy.png), with corresponding transition probability matrix:

$$
M=\left[\begin{array}{rr}
0.3&0.7\\
0.6&0.4
\end{array}\right]\
$$

So, the right eigenvector of this matrix should be the all-ones vector, right? Or more generally, a constant vector. However, the simple code below doesn't give me this answer.

```
    import numpy as np

    M = np.matrix('0.3 0.7; 0.6 0.4')
    u, s, vH = np.linalg.svd(M)
```

In fact, the matrices it returns me are (I rounded the results to ease presentation):

$$
U=\left[\begin{array}{rr}
-0.7298 &-0.6837\\
-0.6837 &0.7298
\end{array}\right],\quad
S=\left[\begin{array}{r r}
1.0055  &0.2984
\end{array}\right],
\quad \mbox{and} \quad
V^*=\left[\begin{array}{rr}
-0.6257 &-0.7800\\
0.7800 & -0.6257
\end{array}\right]
$$

Just to be clear, the right eigenvectors are the rows of $V^*$. As I mentioned, other softwares return me the same result (e.g., [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SVD%20%7B%7B0.3,0.7%7D,%7B0.6,0.4%7D%7D)). These softwares are not all wrong, thus, why isn't the top right eigenvector constant?

Comment: SVD is **singular** value decomposition, not eigenvalue decomposition. It gives you singular values and singular vectors, not eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Try `np.linalg.eig` instead.

Comment: The rows of $V^T$ are eigenvectors for $M^TM$ rather than $M$.